# Hide file paths in attachments sent via email c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here's the code:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:/Program Files (x86)/Software/Extraction/INVOICE_AMOUNT_VS_ORDER_AMOUNT.xlsx"));
```

Appears as "/Program Files (x86)/Software/Extraction/INVOICE_AMOUNT_VS_ORDER_AMOUNT.xlsx" in the mail sent.

I just need the receiver to see the file name.

Comment: There are more overloads of `Attachment` constructor, e.g. [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws(v=vs.110).aspx) (see example there how to add content type with name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are using the wrong slash (path separator).

Change this:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:/Program Files (x86)/Software/Extraction/INVOICE_AMOUNT_VS_ORDER_AMOUNT.xlsx"));
```

To this:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Software\Extraction\INVOICE_AMOUNT_VS_ORDER_AMOUNT.xlsx"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
var path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Software/Extraction/INVOICE_AMOUNT_VS_ORDER_AMOUNT.xlsx";
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Path.GetFileName(path).ToString()));
```

Here is the official link from the msdn site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx